# Tweepy - How to find original tweet id from retweet?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Title might be a little confusing. I'm trying to get the id of the tweet that someone retweeted. So if someone retweets something, I want to get the id of what they retweeted. Is this possible? If so, I'd love an example. Thanks.

Comment: yes, eminently possible, though I've only interacted with twitter through Python by the twitter api wrapper named "twitter", never used tweepy. looking through the tweepy docs it seems like they work in a similar manner.

Comment: If you have a `Status` object, look at the `retweeted_status` attribute.

If set, it represents the original Tweet from which you can reference the `id_str` attribute which is the original Tweet that was retweeted.  I'd give an answer but my Python is rusty so...I comment.  See https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets

Answer (score 3):

```
id_str = retweeted_status.id_str
```

Should do the work.

Tip: Use string version of Id's if you want to store them for better writing performance to csv file.